# MATLAB Newbie - Display image with position

Tags: matlab

i can create an axes and use the axes() to define the axes i want to display my image in it , but that's not working cause i have this message :

http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/s6wNRZF.jpg

there is any other way to display image in the position i want ?

for example :

```
showimg('link',position)
```

my code that i recieve the error from :

```
img = imread(2.png);
axes(handles.axes7);
imshow(img);
```

Comment: asking the same question multiple times under different username will not bring you better answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153461/matlab-newbie-matlab-system-error-the-unsolved-error-message-in-all-time. _Specially when you already did the "multiple asking" with a previous question_

Comment: sorry i need the answer this night i have to give them my last project in the university tomorrow :E

Comment: all right, but now you have the answer, please delete the other similar question then. It's of no use to anyone to have pure duplicates and it just clutters the system.

Comment: you'r right ok thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should directly pass the file name to `imshow` and, then, add the reference to the axis handle when calling imshow:

```
imshow('2.png','parent',handles.axes7)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are right, I've made a mistake (SORRY): the correct way to call imshow is:  imshow('2.png','parent',handles.axes7).